# exception: current-continuation-marks: no corresponding prompt in the continuation: #<continuation-prompt-tag:web>

Tags: scheme, racket

why do i get exception on (redirect/get) in this program

```
#lang web-server
(require web-server/formlets web-server/page) (struct app (nm) #:mutable)
(define (start req) (render-main-page req))
```

this function is to be used by most pages and generates comlete page xexpr by calling each given piece of page generator functions, each of which may embed their urls

```
(define (render-page embed/url a-title blocks)
     (response/xexpr `(html (head (title ,a-title) 
         (body ,@(map (lambda (block) (block embed/url)) blocks))))))
```

this is piece of first page generator function

```
(define (render-action-panel embed/url action)
  `(a ([href ,(embed/url action)]) "New"))
```

this is first page

```
(define/page (render-main-page)
  (local [(define (new-handler req) (render-app-page req (app "new value")))
          (define (panel-block embed/url) (render-action-panel embed/url new-handler))]            
    (render-page embed/url "Title" (list panel-block))))
```

this is piece of second page generator function (represents form)

```
(define (add-app-formlet an-app) (formlet (#%# ,{=> input-string nm}) nm))
(define (render-app-form embed/url an-app save-handler)
  `(div (form ([action ,(embed/url save-handler)][method "POST"])
              (span ,@(formlet-display (add-app-formlet an-app) ))
              (span (input ([type "submit"][value "Save"]))))));)
```

the second form, 
save handler throws exception when trying do post-redirect-get

```
(define/page (render-app-page an-app)
  (local [(define (save-handler req)
            (render-app-page 
             (redirect/get) 
             (set-app-nm! an-app (formlet-process (add-app-formlet an-app) req))))
          (define (form-block embed/url)
            (render-app-form embed/url an-app save-handler ))
          ]
    (render-page embed/url "Title - form: " (list form-block))))

(require web-server/servlet-env)
(serve/servlet start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `redirect/get` are you using?

The one from `web-server/lang/servlet` (which should be used with `#lang web-server`) is different than the one from `web-server/servlet` (which should be used with `#lang racket` (and friends))

This error message means that you are using the one from `web-server/servlet`.

FWIW, `web-server/page` cannot be used with `#lang web-server` because it is just a simple macro over the `send/suspend/dispatch` from `web-server/servlet`.

Comment: i replaced lang with  #lang racket
    (require web-server/http web-server/formlets web-server/page web-server/servlet)